# How to set the block size of hdfs file when running a flink job?

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink

I have a customed file type, format like this: first a header, then a array of big objects. For each file, the length of each objects is the same, and the count of objects is recorded in the header.

Now I want to build a flink job to process this file in parallel. Since the file is huge, I put it in hdfs. And I think the parallel can be done based on the objects.

So here is the question: how should I set the file block size? Maybe the length of each object? But what about the header?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't support split enumeration for the file, then the HDFS block size doesn't really matter, as one sub-task will be processing each file.

If the file is splittable, and you can ensure that each object can fit in a single block, and you ensure that object boundaries are equal to block boundaries, then it's a win.